# ASP.NET Web Project deployed to IIS Express not accessible outside localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have deployed my C# ASP.NET Visual Studio Express 2013 project via the IIS internal Express webserver service.

Locally its great - I can access it at : `http://localhost:56473/hello`

However if from another PC on my internal network I try to access it via :`http://192.168.0.2:56473/hello` it gets an http 400 bad request!?

Any ideas - anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: Yeah, is your _machine_ accessible from the rest of the network? Do you have the site in IIS configured to use that IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Express isn't for external hosting.

If you want to see your work from an external client, install IIS from the programs and features.

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > Internet Information Services.

Comment: Please see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398285/http-403-on-new-iis-deployment

Answer (score 3):

Are you on a desktop (vs. web server)?

On a desktop, IIS Express doesn't allow external connections (obviously for security reasons). Having said that and if you know what you're getting into, here's [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) on how to do that.

Comment: Ok so i tried this - but the command: netsh firewall add portopening TCP 80 IISExpressWeb enable ALL appears to be deprecated - and I am not sure what the new version of this should be?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Nice name BTW :) I haven't worn the IT hat in years but that's a command line version of what you can do via Windows UI -> Control Panel -> Security -> Windows Firewall , or like myself, my box is "managed by McAfee" and its firewall. At the end of the day, you need to open Port X (whatever it is you set IIS Express to listen to) in firewall settings...Hth

Comment: "EdSF i think its a little deeper than this! The firewall is all good. I followed the article and got that point done. However now this happens : http://andyworker.hopto.org:56378/default.aspx - a service unavailable http 503!

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Well assuming you got Firewall stuff out of the way. On the PC you are using to connect to (not the one with IIS), does it "know" where `andyworker.hopto.org` is? It seems to be "real" host on the interwebs, so you have to "intercept" the DNS lookup on that PC by editing it's `hosts` file (arg my IT brain is hurting!). Or, use the IP (of the box where IIS is) to connect (so no DNS resolution). Hth...

Comment: No no - i am using a dynamic dns service - so the response if you go to that URL is accurate and truly being returned from my PC. I am now trying to deploy the application via IIS but getting a set of new errors now!

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Cool - proving that even "errors" are welcome sight :) Tip: start with a plain HTML "hello world" so you can isolate between net/connectivity, IIS, and finally application matters. Best~