# Http 403 on new IIS deployment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis, iis-7, iis-6

Having just asked this question : [ASP.NET Web Project deployed to IIS Express not accessible outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397484/asp-net-web-project-deployed-to-iis-express-not-accessible-outside-localhost) I figured I would just go ahead and install IIS. I did this - and setup a new deployment of my site.

However when you try visiting it : http://andyworker.hopto.org:8080/ you will notice a http 403 error. Googling around I see this post http://sanuja.com/blog/resolving-iis-403-forbidden-access-is-denied which suggests adding a user and giving it read write execute for IIS however that bit where I add the user fails - as I don't think the user exists?

Can anybody help me here? I am very new to IIS having never deployed something before and having just installed it - but something simple here feels quite unintuitive.

Andy

Comment: I'm getting a 404 though... Are you hosting the site as a Virtual Directory?

Comment: I am not sure...? How can I check

Comment: Just go to IIS manager...Check if your site is under "Sites" (in which case it's a normal site)...Or go to Sites->Default Web Site and check if your site has a "globe icon" (application) or a "folder icon" (virtual directory). Anyway, about the users part did you try to give permissions to your "Users" group? There should be one just like "SYSTEM", "Administrators". You probably don't have to create a new user. If you do try to create a new user, give the name "IIS_IUSRS"..and not "ISS_IUSRS" as written in the blog.